# Compute change from baseline by id

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some longitudinal data which is animal_id by study day, as shown below:
[image]

How would I create a column which computes the change from baseline by each animal_id? Here, baseline would be where ord = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `transform` `first` , notice this assuming your df is sorted already

```
df['New']=df['Body_Weight']-df.groupby('Animal_id')['Body_weight'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, if you don't want to sort your data, you can use a surrogate data frame with the value of body weight for ord=0 and then merge it to the previous data frame.

```
df_ord = df.query("ord==0").rename(columns={'body_weight':'body_weight_base'})
df_ord = df_ord.drop('ord',axis=1)
df = df.merge(df_ord)
df['change'] = df['body_weight'] - df['body_weight_base']
```